# Using P(X=n) in normal distribution questions.

Tags: probability, proof-verification, normal-distribution

Firstly, I know you don't use $P(X=n)$ in normal distribution questions.
But I have a question where I'm kind of baffled on how to write the probability.

> A scientist noted that  36%  of temperature measurements were 4°C lower than the average.

I want to say I'd write $P(X<μ-4) = 0.36$  But it just doesn't make sense to me. I would instinctively write $P(X=μ-4) = 0.36$ because I'm looking at values where temperatures are exactly 4°C lower and not at least 4°C lower than the average. So where am I going wrong in understanding this?

Comment: The question is poorly stated.  If $36\%$ were exactly 4°C lower than the average, it certainly wouldn't be a normal distribution, because it wouldn't be continuous.  It could be that what is meant is that $36\%$ were at least 4°C lower, or perhaps that $36\%$ were between $3.5$ and $4.5$ degrees lower.

Comment: I believe the correct interpretation is $$ Pr(\mu - 4 \leq X) = .36$$

Comment: @RHowe Let us hope you believe the correct interpretation is not what you wrote but $$P(X<\mu-4)=0.36$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to question this. I think the fault is in the statement

> A scientist noted that  36%  of temperature measurements were 4°C lower than the average.

Imagine taking lots of temperature measurements and finding that $36\%$ were *exactly* 4°C. It wouldn’t happen, since temperature is a continuous variable.
Perhaps it should state:

> A scientist noted that  36%  of temperature measurements were 4°C lower than the average, to the nearest whole degree.

Or

> A scientist noted that  36%  of temperature measurements were at least 4°C lower than the average.

In either of these cases I’m sure you can figure out what probability to use.